# How to decrease delaytime on Gesturedetect of Android

Tags: android, listener, gesture

I am coding for Getsture Function of Android Phone.
But I have the problem.

When Drawing gesture on the screen, **"OnGesturePerformedListener"** Function is called late.

This delaytime makes my apple seems having lack.

== xml code ================================================

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestures" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gestureStrokeType="single"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fadeEnabled="true"
    android:fadeDuration="0"   
    >
```

=============================================================

I have coded along "http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html"

Please Help me solve the probleam.